# Confusing type warning when constructing list with Union contents

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

Consider this example:

```
from typing import Union


def f(xs: list[Union[type, str]]):
    pass


f(([int] * 2) + [int, ' ', str])
f(([int] * 3) + [' ', str])
f(([int] * 3) + [' ', int])
```

I would consider the first two calls to `f()` to be equivalent. But PyCharm flags the second one with a warning: "`Expected type 'list[Type[int]]' (matched generic type 'list[_T]'), got 'list[str | Type[str]]' instead`"

As if to further confuse me, the third call does not have this issue.

Am I missing some type hint subtlety here, or is it PyCharm that's making a mistake? (in which case I'll go and file a bug report)

I got the sense that PyCharm is too trigger-happy to decide that, apparently, we're dealing with a list of types, which matches the required `list[Union[type, str]]`, but then forgets that this is the actual requirement and then stumbles when the next list starts with a string (which is of course not a type). But if that were the case, it makes no sense that the third statement works...

Of course the code above is not trying to achieve anything, this is just the minimal example that I could come up with that displays behaviour I'm seeing in actual code, where it actually makes sense for me to pass a list of mixed strings and types.

It seems that the problem only occurs if there's a mismatch between the types in the two halves of the concatenation, because this is fine:

```
f(([str] * 3) + [' ', str])
```

Comment: Your type hints are correct, if you look carefully at the second part of the warning it's written with a pipe `|` which would suggest your project is configured to use a Python 3.10 interpreter because that's the new [Union type syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#union-type) although your type hint is written with the older 3.9 syntax. I tried this using Python 3.9 and I get the same warning (only the syntax of the second part of the warning differing) I've seen this kind of linter bug before...

Comment: Yes, it was written an tested using 3.10, but as you mention, the problem is the same using 3.9 - that is, there's not really a problem, just warnings from the IDE. I suppose I better file a bug report then :)

Comment: Posting this on the JetBrains bugtracker is right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been reported as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53036

I'll update and accept this answer if the outcome requires some change in settings, or I'll delete the question if the issue is simply fixed.

Comment: FYI, usually these linter bugs get resolved within reasonable time (it's a problem more users don't report them on the JetBrains tracker). It's also not necessary to delete the thread because often users will be locked into using older PyCharm versions if they are working with projects requiring older Python versions (so this thread might continue being useful long after the bug has been fixed in updated versions of the IDE.)